# Is there a reason to create set_pose service in global namespace in EKF node?

Tags: navigation, ekf, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using [robot_localization](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization) package under melodic to fuse odom, IMU and GPS RTK data. I followed the tutorials and use two EKFs and `navsat_transform` node.

I was wondering if there is any reason for creating the `/set_pose` service and topic subscriber using global node handle: https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/melodic-devel/src/ros_filter.cpp#L1010-L1016 ? My problem is that having two EKFs running I cannot use `/set_pose` service for both of them because only one is available (probably due to naming clash?):

```
root@2c1c12b2e1b7:~# rosnode info /ekf_se_odom -q
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/ekf_se_odom]
 ...    
Services: 
 * /ekf_se_odom/enable
 * /ekf_se_odom/get_loggers
 * /ekf_se_odom/set_logger_level
 * /ekf_se_odom/toggle

root@2c1c12b2e1b7:~# rosnode info /ekf_se_map -q
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/ekf_se_map]
...
Services: 
 * /ekf_se_map/enable
 * /ekf_se_map/get_loggers
 * /ekf_se_map/set_logger_level
 * /ekf_se_map/toggle
 * /set_pose
```

I could use the `/set_pose` topic for this purpose, but one of the EKFs should get the message with `header.frame_id="map"` and the other with `header.frame_id="odom"`.

The reason why I want to do it is I'm manually setting datum for `navsat_transform` after moving some distance to determine heading based on GPS. My IMU does not provide reliable heading after start hence I want to deduce it from short straight line motion and set datum and then I have to reset the EKFs since `/set_datum` also resets the GPS-based odometry published by `navsat_transfrom` (which would cause jumps in the `ekf_se_map`).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357021/is-there-a-reason-to-create-set_pose-service-in-global-namespace-in-ekf-node?/) by [mpanek06](https://answers.ros.org/users/40345/mpanek06/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any reason that you can't just [remap](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/Remapping%20Arguments) the services?

```
<node name="ekf_se_odom" ...>
  <remap from="/set_pose" to="/set_pose_odom"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2020-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mpanek06](https://answers.ros.org/users/40345/mpanek06/) on 2020-07-14**:
Thanks for the reply! Of course I can, I don't know why I didn't think about that... I guess that fact that other services use private namespace fooled me a bit. Thanks!